# count consecutive days where temp is below 0

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get a count of the consecutive days in my db that the temperature was below 0. I can get a total count of the total days below 0 using a select count but not the consecutive number of days. I then want to be able to show the first and last day as well as the count.
The table is updated every minute.

Assume I have a minimal table such as:

```
    datetime            temp
    11/14/2014 7:21:31  -2.4
    11/14/2014 7:22:31  -2.4
    11/15/2014 5:03:31  2.4
    11/15/2014 5:04:31  2.4
    11/16/2014 5:10:31  -0.2
    11/16/2014 5:11:31  -0.2
    11/17/2014 5:13:31  -0.2
    11/17/2014 5:14:31  -0.2
    11/18/2014 5:15:31  2
    11/18/2014 5:16:31  2
```

In the example, the consecutive days would be 2, the first date is 11/16/2014 and the last date is 11/17/2014 and the total days (I can get this) would be 3.

Thanks for looking.

Edit:
I want the longest consecutive streak. As to how I got the data, it is a simple select statement:
        Select datetime, temp From mytable;

Comment: This is mysql, so those are not dates ;-) And what if there was more than one set of consecutive days - 14-15 and 17-18, say.

Comment: Yes, I just exported the dates and temps from a sample. It's a datetime column. As to your question, I'm looking for the longest consecutive streak of days and it should be the earliest (date-wise).

Comment: Please amend your question accordingly.

Comment: [also, either you want the earliest (date-wise), or you want the longest - you can't have both (or only coincidentally)] - and how exactly did you 'export' those dates !?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following...

The data set...

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

 CREATE TABLE my_table
 ( dt datetime NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
 , temp DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL);

 INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
 ('2014-11-14 7:21:31',  -2.4),
 ('2014-11-14 7:22:31',  -2.4),
 ('2014-11-15 5:03:31',  2.4),
 ('2014-11-15 5:04:31',  2.4),
 ('2014-11-16 5:10:31',  -0.2),
 ('2014-11-16 5:11:31',  -0.2),
 ('2014-11-17 5:13:31',  -0.2),
 ('2014-11-17 5:14:31',  -0.2),
 ('2014-11-18 5:15:31',  2),
 ('2014-11-18 5:16:31',  2);
```

Solution 1 - If you just want to know the length of the longest run...

```
 SELECT MAX(@count := IF(a.result = b.result, @count + 1, 1)) LongestRun
   FROM 
      ( SELECT DISTINCT DATE(x.dt) date
                      , COALESCE(y.temp,x.temp) < 0 result 
                   FROM my_table x 
                   LEFT 
                   JOIN my_table y 
                     ON DATE(y.dt) = DATE(x.dt) AND y.temp < 0
      ) a
  CROSS
   JOIN (SELECT @count := 0) vars
   LEFT
   JOIN 
      ( SELECT DISTINCT DATE(x.dt) date
                      , COALESCE(y.temp,x.temp) < 0 result 
                   FROM my_table x 
                   LEFT 
                   JOIN my_table y 
                     ON DATE(y.dt) = DATE(x.dt) AND y.temp < 0
      ) b
     ON b.date = a.date - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
  WHERE a.result = 1; 

 +------------+
 | LongestRun |
 +------------+
 |          2 |
 +------------+
```

Solution 2 - If you want some of the other information too

```
 SELECT a.date start
      , MIN(c.date) end
      , DATEDIFF(MIN(c.date),a.date) + 1 LongestRun
   FROM
      ( SELECT DISTINCT DATE(x.dt) date
                      , COALESCE(y.temp,x.temp) < 0 result 
                   FROM my_table x 
                   LEFT 
                   JOIN my_table y 
                     ON DATE(y.dt) = DATE(x.dt) AND y.temp < 0
      ) a
   LEFT 
   JOIN 
      ( SELECT DISTINCT DATE(x.dt) date
                      , COALESCE(y.temp,x.temp) < 0 result 
                   FROM my_table x 
                   LEFT 
                   JOIN my_table y 
                     ON DATE(y.dt) = DATE(x.dt) AND y.temp < 0
      ) b 
     ON b.date = a.date - INTERVAL 1 DAY
    AND b.result = 1
   LEFT 
   JOIN 
      ( SELECT DISTINCT DATE(x.dt) date
                      , COALESCE(y.temp,x.temp) < 0 result 
                   FROM my_table x 
                   LEFT 
                   JOIN my_table y 
                     ON DATE(y.dt) = DATE(x.dt) AND y.temp < 0
      ) c 
     ON c.date >= a.date 
    AND c.result = 1
   LEFT 
   JOIN 
      ( SELECT DISTINCT DATE(x.dt) date
                      , COALESCE(y.temp,x.temp) < 0 result 
                   FROM my_table x 
                   LEFT 
                   JOIN my_table y 
                     ON DATE(y.dt) = DATE(x.dt) AND y.temp < 0
      ) d 
     ON d.date = c.date + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    AND d.result = 1
  WHERE a.result = 1
    AND b.date IS NULL
    AND c.date IS NOT NULL
    AND d.date IS NULL
  GROUP 
     BY a.date
  ORDER 
     BY LongestRun DESC 
  LIMIT 1;

  +------------+------------+------------+
  | start      | end        | LongestRun |
  +------------+------------+------------+
  | 2014-11-16 | 2014-11-17 |          2 |
  +------------+------------+------------+
```

For the aggregate data, just issue a separate query.

Comment: Thumbs up for your approach which is even way faster than mine (2ms vs. 5ms).

Answer (score 0):

You need to join your table to itself with `date` field. Something like this:

```
SELECT dt, temp FROM
(
   SELECT date(t1.`datetime`) as dt, t1.temp  
   FROM mytable t1 LEFT JOIN mytable AS t2 
   ON date(t2.`datetime`) = (date(t1.`datetime`)-interval 1 day) 
) TMP WHERE temp < 0
```

Comment: (incidentally, datetime is specifically excluded from the list of reserved words - but I agree with the sentiment, if not the solution!)

Answer (score -1):

Use custom variables and some increment logic to count the number of freezing days (temperature below zero). This should get you started

```
SELECT 
        t1.endofstreakdate, 
        IF(t1.freeze > 0, @m := @m + 1, @m := t1.freeze) AS streak 
FROM (
        SELECT 
                DATE(t.datetime) AS endofstreakdate, 
                DAYOFYEAR(t.datetime) AS doy, 
                MIN(t.temp) AS low, 
                IF(MIN(t.temp) < 0, @i := @i + 1, @i := @i - @i) AS freeze 
        FROM (
                SELECT 
                        @i := 0, 
                        @m := 0
                ) v, 
                temperature t 
        GROUP BY doy
) t1 

LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
                DAYOFYEAR(t.datetime) AS doy, 
                MIN(t.temp) AS low, 
                IF(MIN(t.temp) < 0, @i := @i + 1, @i := @i - @i) AS freeze 
        FROM (
                SELECT 
                        @i := 0, 
                        @m := 0
                ) v, 
                temperature t 
        GROUP BY doy
) t2 

        ON t2.doy = t1.doy - 1
```

This will give you a list of all unique dates (without time) and the number of days the temperature has been below 0 like

```
    endofstreakdate     streak
    2014-11-14              1
    2014-11-15              0
    2014-11-16              1
    2014-11-17              2
    2014-11-18              0
```

You can now `ORDER BY streak DESC, endofstreakdate ASC LIMIT 1` to get the earliest occurrence of the longest freezing period (it returns the number of days it has been below zero and the last day of that period).